# Random number from shuffle infinite loop

Tags: php, random, shuffle

Hi I am looking for a simple solution to shuffle a range of random number, then take 5 number from the range and put in a slider. Currently my code is like this, which end in infinite loop:

```
$slides = range(1,30);
shuffle($slides);
$count = 0; //infinite loop guard
do{
  foreach ($slides as $slide) {
  echo "<img src=\"images/slider_".$slide.".jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n";
  }
} while ($count<5);
```

There is a lot of example in Javascript but I can't replicate that for PHP. This code is for generating random image for a slider, but limit to only 5 slide at a time. A total 30 images available.

Comment: You never incremented `$count`.

Comment: How many images do you need at the end? Just 5 or 30? Or maybe 150?

Comment: Images need is also a variable, but for the example, 5 is okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the mistake here is that you should have incremented `$count` inside the loop; without it, its value is stuck at 0. Also, you were iterating over the full list of values inside the `do {} while`; perhaps that was intended, but given your requirement of 5 slides at a time, I doubt that would have been correct.

Instead of shooting yourself in the foot with your own loops, just [slice](http://php.net/array_slice) what you need:

```
$slides = range(1,30);
shuffle($slides);
foreach (array_slice($slides, 0, 5) as $slide) {
    echo "<img src=\"images/slider_".$slide.".jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n";
}
```

The `array_slice()` function creates a new array, starting from index 0 (first item) and of length 5.

Comment: Thanks Jack. This is the result of failed basic knowledge from me :(

Comment: @FadliSaad I wasn't sure if the answer was correct, but I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

When you're using a incremental counter, it's easier to use for loops :

```
$slides = range(1,30);
shuffle($slides);
$count = 0; //infinite loop guard
for ( $count = 0 ; $count < 5 ; $count++){
    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        echo "<img src=\"images/slider_".$slide.".jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ibi0tux as well. Your solution fit the original code. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

You're not incrementing `$count` within your loop, so it's always zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
$slides = range(1,30);
shuffle($slides);
$count = 0; //infinite loop guard
do{
  foreach ($slides as $slide) {
  $count++;
  echo "<img src=\"images/slider_".$slide.".jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n";
  }
} while ($count<5);
```

It's obvious that it's a infinity loop cause you don't increment $count. Do that with `$count++;`

Answer (score 1):

increment `$count`, like:

```
foreach ($slides as $slide) {
  echo "<img src=\"images/slider_".$slide.".jpg\" alt=\"\" />\n";
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: Sudhir, your solution works too. Obviously it is my ignorance that lead to the increment being left out.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$slides = range(1,30);
shuffle($slides);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++): ?>
    <img src="images/slider_<?php echo $slides[$i]; ?>.jpg" alt="" /><br />
<?php endfor ?>
```

Comment: antony, your solution was most elegant!